# C# .NET AS2 communication

Tags: c#, .net, edi, communicator

I like to ask for some guidance on this topic of sending and receiving files via AS2 or AS3 communications protocol via a .NET C# implementation.  I have search for examples or explanation of how you would implement this communication layer to send and receive EDI documents as well as other types of documents.  I have built my own EDI document generator and reader.  It's linked to my eCommerce systems.  We have been working with VCommerce and CommerceHUB for a number of years.  What i can't seem to find much information on is an implementation of what the communication layer looks like for AS2.  I realize the second part to all of this is the generation of certificates for encryption and decryption but I think I have an idea on how to implement that or just create the certificates manually if possible.  Can you guys point me to anything that can either show me an example of the standards to use to send the HTTP message or something like that?  I have used the /n Software for the communications part up until now but I would really like to do this myself so that its 100% integrated.  For anyone who needs just the server they are great and worth the cost.  Very stable and easy to implement.  For me I have grown beyond being able to use them and need to build my own.

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Are you sure ActionScript-2 tag is appropriate/realted to your question? AS2/AS3 seem te related to some communication protocaol rather than Flash scripting language...

Comment: Thnx.  It's not.  I tried to type in "as2" and i guess it selected the as2 action script option.

Comment: The AS2 specification is RFC4130: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4130.txt It uses HTTP to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

The specification is an open standard as Porges commented.  You are reinventing the wheel, just like with your EDI translator.  Perhaps there is no budget for a software tool that does the work for you?  I'd be interested in what your "reader" looks like. Does it compare to EDI Notepad (a free EDI reader from Liaison)?

If you feel /n is not scalable, there are many other MFT / integrated products that are.  Were you aware that there was an AS2 certification process by the Drummond Group (http://www.drummondgroup.com/index.php/b2b-certified-products/certified-products/as2)?  Some partners require Drummond Certified AS2 connections (although not as much as there were in years past as Wal-mart dropped the requirement).

What are you going to do for certificate management? Integrate with Windows (which handles certs poorly IMO), or build your own? Partner management / AS2 names / Connections? Are you going to build functionality to handle both synchronous and asynchronous MDNs?  What about error trapping / emailing users of errors?  Seems to me there's a reason these commercial software platforms exist that do all of this functionality already.  The time you spend building the tool is going to cost just as much or more to buy something that already works.

Products I've used that I've been able to 100% integrate into my platforms through the years:
Cleo Lexicom is scalable, and cost effective.
Liaison ECS offers unlimited partners (but requires SQL Server)
Axway Synchrony Interchange is flexible

Comment: Thank you all for great info.  Porges, you are right, I feel like I am re-inventing the wheel but no budget so no real choice. I planed to used Windows certificate. The partner management part is already built  minus the certificate part and the communication part.  I will first take a look at your suggestions before i really start any major coding.

Answer (score 1):

Try \n Software's http://www.nsoftware.com/ibiz/edi/

I used this to build services into a commercial file exchange application, and I've seen at least two of my favorite competitors use it to build ASx services into their commercial applications too.